# Is switching between first, second and third person in this context OK?

Tags: writing-advice

As this is my first question here I'd like to make a short introduction. I work in Estonia. As one of very few native speakers I landed a job as a content writer / proofreader. I'm not a great writer, or even a good one, therefore I suspect I will be posting here often!

I'm proofreading a news article for the company's website.

The article starts off by referring to the company in third person - (company name) is pleased to announce (announcement).

It then shifts to first person for most of the rest of the article - I, we, our.

The final paragraph shifts to second person and addresses the reader with instructions and a call to action - your (stuff) approved for you etc.

I've always understood articles should be written from one perspective. Should I rewrite it?

Any advice and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Addressing the customer is not really shifting anything—it's just including the reader (who will always be in the second person). The sender (writer) can be either first or third person, and here maintaining consistency helps avoid ambiguity and stylistic messes; but I think starting out with “[Company Name] is happy to reveal our new product” _vel sim_ works well enough as being all first-person that it doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: Thank you, definitely something to consider. It can, at times, be really difficult to decipher text here. Any article here is written without any regard or attempt to follow the various language rules - which is understandable. Often articles are written in English by following Russian or Estonian rules. I think it was safer to rewrite the article as shifting presences  became extremely confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've always understood articles should be written from one perspective.

I believe it generally produces the clearest result.

> Should I rewrite it?

I would seriously consider doing so.

> The article starts off by referring to the company in third person - (company name) is pleased to announce (announcement).
>
> It then shifts to first person for most of the rest of the article - I, we, our.

This shift is probably acceptable but you should not mix I and we. You should not convey uncertainty over number. I'd pick "we" because corporate organisations are an individual legal entity, but not one capable of articulating its own individual thought - a spokesperson does that on behalf of the organisation's members. If you use "I", the reader is likely to think the spokesperson is writing about his or her personal opinion and not necessarily reflecting official corporate policy or views.

Comment: I agree with this, though I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with the shifts described. The final paragraph doesn't sound like a shift in perspective so much as the "we" from earlier addressing the "you" of the customer base. I definitely agree that you should not mix "I" and "we" unless part of the article actually refers to the writer alone while part refers to the whole company.

Comment: Thank you for the comments they were very helpful! I rewrote the article from a third person perspective. I think that was best since it was a news article.