# Is it proper to switch from the third person singular (The Department of Environment) to the first person plural (we) in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I often have to translate sentences such as:

> **The Department of Environment**  has offices everywhere in the country, and **we** would love for you to join us [us as in "the whole department, and not a specific team].

Or:

> **The Police Department** is assigning as many resources possible to the case, but **we** [the Police Department] cannot counter these threats alone

I've been told quite a few times that a switch from the third person singular to the first person plural like that is to be avoided in French (supposedly because "we" could refer to anything and cause confusion, even in simple cases like these), and was wondering if the same kind of rule applies in English.

I couldn't find any grammar or style guide to help me with this. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is switching between first, second and third person in this context OK?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170151/is-switching-between-first-second-and-third-person-in-this-context-ok) As that says, it's fine in this example but you don't want to switch too often or unnecessarily.